# CPU Out of memory when training a model with pytorch lightning

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, pytorch-lightning, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to train a BERT model on my data using the `Trainer` class from `pytorch-lightning`. However, I encountered an out-of-memory exception in the **CPU memory**.

Here is the code:

```
from transformers.data.data_collator import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset = load_dataset('text', data_path)  # The dataset is only 33GB, while my GPU has 350GB 
 of RAM.

class BertDataModule(pl.LightningDataModule):
   def __init__(self, dataset, train_split, batch_size, data_collator):
      super().__init__()
      self.train_dataset = None
      self.dataset = dataset
      self.collator = data_collator
      self.batch_size = batch_size
      self.train_split = train_split

   def train_dataloader(self):
      return torch.utils.data.DataLoader(self.train_dataset, batch_size=self.batch_size, 
      collate_fn=self.collator, num_workers=30)
   # I defined the similar methods for val_dataloader, test_dataloader, and predict_dataloader.

bert_collator = DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=bert_tokenizer) 
bert_data_module = BertDataModule(dataset=my_dataset['train'], train_split=0.98, 
batch_size=32, data_collator=bert_collator)
bert_model = BertModel(...)

trainer = pl.Trainer(devices=1, max_epochs=50, logger=comment_logger, accelerator='gpu', 
 precision=16, val_check_interval=50000, callbacks=[checkpoint_callbacks])

trainer.fit(bert_model, datamodule=bert_data_module) # Crash due to CPU OOM here
```

My code crashed due to an out-of-memory (OOM) error, even though my data is only 33GB and my CPU memory in the OpenShift pod is 350GB.

Do you have any idea what could be causing the memory of the CPU to continue increasing during training?

Thank you very much.

Comment: reduce your batch_size

Comment: I tried but still OOM @Hemanthkumar

Comment: else eliminate unwanted layers (to reduce no of neurons which may gives some space to ram or final remedy to reduce some training data )

Comment: During training you need to store the model, all the gradients for all parameters and all the activations during forward path, so it can take quite a lof of memory if you have a big model , a big batch and each sample alone take a lot of data. Also data usually take much more space in RAM as they are usually compressed when on hard disk. However the memory consumption should not increase during training but stay rather constant... When does it crash exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

During training you need to store the model, all the gradients for all parameters and all the activations during forward path, so it can take quite a lof of memory if you have a big model , a big batch and each sample alone take a lot of data. Also data usually take much more space in RAM as they are usually compressed when on hard disk. However the memory consumption should not increase during training but stay rather constant... When does it crash exactly ?

Also, do you have a GPU or CPU ??? YOur title says CPU, but your post says a 350GB GPU. (btw i'm rather skeptical since there is currently no GPU with that much memory that exists to my knowlege). If it crashes from CPU then this means you simply cant load the entire dataset in RAM. If it crashes from GPU then your batch+model cant fit in your GPU setup during training.

Comment: Hi, The crash is after a few hours. I have a GPU and I run the training using openshift, so I have CPU memory of 350GB (OOM during the training).  The dataset is only 33GB so I'm not sure why the CPU memory usage continues to grow during the training until the crash.  I used `Dataset` (`load_dataset` and `DataLoader`). Do you have an idea?